# text style with gradient color

Tags: android, textview, gradient

I would like to set the style for TextView. It should have the  black stroke on letters and be of a gradient colour (horizontal one) to be used on multiple texts.

In case if I am creating the textstyle with one solid colour and then apply that to TextView it works fine (apart stroke). In case if I try to set the drawable recourse for gradient colour and try to apply it later on, it does not work, the adnroid app is not launching, looping back.  But have here doubts is it possible to assign textcolor as @drawable/..., or only @color/... would work?

Tried to use Shader option - is able to set the gradients as I want, but it applies only to one particular text line, but not to multiple. Is there any way how to do this?

Or is it possible to create such text style?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible directly, but you may implement your own type of span to do this. Have a look at [ForegroundColorSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan) and try to implement a similar class with the functionality that you need.